# Xamarin Forms IsEnabled MultiTrigger on Entry is not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, multitrigger

I am trying to get an entry IsEnabled property to set based on 2 different boolean values using a MultiTrigger in Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.726. I have also tried in the last stable 4.5 version too.

Unfortunately the `Entry IsEnabled` property seems to remain at whatever the `Setter`'s value is set to (in the case, true).

I have tried the two types of BindingCondition in the below code sample. The first (uncommented) conditions are bound to the IsVisible properties of two other elements on the page. The `StackLayout` and the `Image` will toggle their visibility as expected, however the `Entry IsEnabled` will not changed.

The second snip of code binds directly to the values in the ViewModel, implenenting INotifyPropertyChanged but has the exact same result where the `IsEnabled` value does not change.

I have run out of ideas and i'm starting to wonder if this is a bug with Xamarin and MultiTriggers. There doesn't seem to be a huge amount of people using them online, and those that do I have mine set out in what seems to be the most common way in the first set of code.

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="ButtonsStack" IsVisible="{Binding Invoice.Editable}">
   <!-- Content Here -->    
</StackLayout>

<Image x:Name="InvoiceImage" IsVisible="{Binding IsUploadInvoice}" />

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
    <Entry Text="{Binding Invoice.TotalAmount}">
        <Entry.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger TargetType="Entry">
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ButtonsStack}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True"/>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference InvoiceImage}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True"/>

                    <!--<BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Invoice.Editable}" Value="True"/>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding IsUploadInvoice}" Value="True"/>-->

                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        <Entry.Triggers>
    <Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: In your code the Trigger will not have any effect. The `IsEnabled` property is same before and after the trigger conditions are met. The `IsEnabled` should be set to `False` initially when you declare the entry in your XAML. When trigger conditions are met, the `IsEnabled` is set to true. When any of the conditions fail, the `IsEnabled` will revert back to inital set value.

Comment: @zafar thanks this solved the issue.
Although thinking about it, why doesn't the page validate the condition when it appears? Other bindings apply properly when appearing so why not these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As zafar said, you need to set **Entry IsEnable="False" by default**, when all the conditions are true, the setter makes the Entry's IsEnabled property true.

```
<StackLayout>
            <Entry IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Invoice.TotalAmount}">
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Entry">
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ButtonsStack}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True" />
                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference InvoiceImage}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True" />

                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
```

About Multi triggers, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers

Comment: *sigh* this was exactly it. Feel like a dum dum. Thank you.